# Mimicking dynamic name resolution of javascript at compile time

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction, transpiler

My question is how typescript mimics at compile time the name resolution and binding process which javascript does at runtime. Does it simulate the runtime somehow using some control flow graph etc. or some other technique is used. I know that scope chain is build statically in javascript so that part is easy to mirror but how does name binding phase works in typescript which is purely done at runtime in javascript.